# Batch script : for looping on my local directory instead of my remote directory

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

I'm writing some Batch code and I'm in front of a problem.
I'm working on it since 2 days, I don't understand why my loop 'For' doing this.

The batch file is launch by C# process with 3 args

Here is my code :

```
set lastname=%1
set firstname=%2
set init=%3
echo open my_remote_add>info.ftp
echo user>>info.ftp
echo pwd>>info.ftp
echo cd "dir/subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir" >> info.ftp 
echo lcd C:\DIR\SUBDIR>>info.ftp
echo prompt>>info.ftp
echo mput *.e*>>info.ftp
set directory=dir
echo %directory%>>info.ftp
::##My probleme is here ##
for /f %%f in ('%directory% /b *.e*') do echo %%f>>info.ftp
::## %directory% show my remote dir, but echo %%f show locals files name with extension .e* instead of remotes directory files name##
echo bye >> info.ftp
ftp -s:info.ftp
pause`
```

I've no idea why it's looping on my local directory instead of my remote directory.
If someone have some idea ?
Thanks.
Regards,
David

EDIT :: Problem solved

Hi.

I totally rebuild my mind.
The problem was : dir is the WorkingDirectory I set on my C# exe.

```
var proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"C:\DIR\SUBDIR\SUBSUBDIR\exportFTP.bat";
proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\DIR\SUBDIR";
proc.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", str2, str3, str4);
Process.Start(proc);
```

After that, i thought it was easiest to copy files I wanted to transfert in a temp directory and run my script on it.

Here is my alternative code :

```
@echo off
set lastname=%1
set firstname=%2
set init=%3
set RemotePath=remotedir/remotesubdir/remotesubdir/remotesubdir
mkdir temp
set LocalPath=C:\DIR\SUBDIR\temp
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.e0*') do copy %%f temp\%lastname%_%firstname%_%init%_%%f>>info.ftp
echo open remote_adress>info.ftp
echo user>>info.ftp
echo pwd>>info.ftp
echo lcd %LocalPath%>>info.ftp 
echo cd %RemotePath% /d>>info.ftp 
echo prompt>>info.ftp
echo mput *.e0*>>info.ftp
echo bye >> info.ftp
ftp -s:info.ftp
del info.ftp
rmdir /s /q temp
move /y "C:\DIR\SUBDIR\*.e0*" "C:\DIR\SUBDIR\SUBDIR\"
```

Thanks again @Compo

Comment: Instead of including your solution in your question, I strongly recommend that you post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing `CD` to `CD /D`:

```
@Echo Off

set lastname=%1
set firstname=%2
set init=%3

set directory=dir

>info.ftp (
    echo open my_remote_add
    echo user
    echo pwd
    echo cd /d "dir/subdir/subsubdir/subsubsubdir"
    echo lcd C:\DIR\SUBDIR
    echo prompt
    echo mput *.e*
    echo %directory%
    echo for /f "delims=" %%f in ('%directory% /b *.e*') do echo %%f
    echo bye)

ftp -s:info.ftp

pause
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I tried your idea, but i get this error : 550 /d: No such file or directory. What the goal of this option ? (/d)

Comment: After some tries, cd /d work like that : cd "dir/subdir/......" /d. The option is need after the destination.(/d = Change drive ;) thanks for the option) But it's not working at the final, i'm still looping on the local directory.